Codegen SymPy matrix
I have the following code where Aij and Bij are matrix of Sympy expressions :
test=codegen([('matA11',A11),('matA21',A21),('matB11',B11),('matB21',B21),('matA12',A12),('matA22',A22),('matB12',B12),('matB22',B22)],'f95','path',to_files=True)

This form a system of equations that I am using inside a code to solve an eigenvalue problem.
Currently to fill up the matrix to solve the eigenvalue problem, I am doing in it by hand, the reason for that it is because I need to do a summation on the different cos(theta) and fill the big matrix for the Eigenvalue problem for each spherical layer (write the full matrix directly with Symply will create directly matrix of huge size like 1000x1000 at least and I don't want that)
call matA11(Gam1(i1,j),Om(i1,j),r2mu(i1,j),r2z(i1,j),drmudz(i1,j),dgdmu(j),dgdz(j),dPdmu(i1,j), &
                        dPdz(i1,j),rmu(i1,j),rz(i1,j),dRhodz(i1,j),dFlm(l2,j),g(j),real(l2,kind=dp) &
                        ,real(m,kind=dp),mu(j),P(i1,j),r(i1,j), &
                        Rho(i1,j),Sigma_0,Flm(l2,j),Flm(l1,j),A11bis)
                
                    call matA12(Gam1(i1,j),rmu(i1,j),rz(i1,j),g(j),mu(j),P(i1,j),r(i1,j),Rho(i1,j),Flm(l2,j),Flm(l1,j),A12bis)

                    call matA21(Gam1(i1,j),Om(i1,j),drmudz(i1,j),d2Flm(l2,j),dgdmu(j),dPdmu(i1,j) &
                        ,dPdz(i1,j),rmu(i1,j),rz(i1,j),dFlm(l2,j),dFlm(l2p,j),g(j), &
                        real(m,kind=dp),mu(j),P(i1,j),r(i1,j) &
                        ,Rho(i1,j),sigma_0,Flm(l2,j),Flm(l1,j),Flm(l2p,j),A21bis)

                    call matA22(rmu(i1,j),rz(i1,j),dFlm(l2,j),g(j), &
                        real(m,kind=dp),mu(j),r(i1,j) &
                        ,Flm(l1,j),Flm(l2p,j),A22bis)

                    call matB11(AmuSymPy(j),AzetaSymPy(j),Gam1(i1,j),Om(i1,j) &
                        ,dOmdmu(i1,j),dOmdz(i1,j),rmu(i1,j),&
                        rz(i1,j),dRhodmu(i1,j),dFlm(l2,j),g(j) &
                        ,real(m,kind=dp),mu(j),P(i1,j),r(i1,j), &
                        Rho(i1,j),Sigma_0,Flm(l2,j),Flm(l1,j),Flm(l1p,j),B11bis)

                    call matB12(Gam1(i1,j),P(i1,j),Rho(i1,j),Flm(l2,j),Flm(l1,j),B12bis)
                
                    call matB21(AmuSymPy(j),Om(i1,j),&
                        dOmdmu(i1,j),dPdmu(i1,j),rmu(i1,j),&
                        dFlm(l2,j),dFlm(l2p,j),g(j) &
                        ,real(m,kind=dp),mu(j),r(i1,j), &
                        Rho(i1,j),Sigma_0,Flm(l2,j),Flm(l1,j),Flm(l2p,j),&
                        Flm(l1p,j),B21bis)

                    ! call matB21(AmuSymPy(j),Om(i1,j),d2Pdmu(i1,j), &
                    !     r2mu(i1,j),d2Flm(l2,j),d2Flm(l2p,j),&
                    !     dOmdmu(i1,j),dPdmu(i1,j),rmu(i1,j),&
                    !     dRhodmu(i1,j),dFlm(l2,j),dFlm(l2p,j),g(j),real(l2,kind=dp) &
                    !     ,real(m,kind=dp),mu(j),r(i1,j), &
                    !     Rho(i1,j),Sigma_0,Flm(l2,j),Flm(l1,j),Flm(l2p,j),&
                    !     Flm(l1p,j),B21bis)

                    call matB22(dFlm(l2,j),dFlm(l2p,j) &
                        ,real(m,kind=dp),mu(j), &
                        Rho(i1,j),Flm(l2,j),Flm(l1,j),Flm(l2p,j),Flm(l1p,j),B22bis)
                    

                
                    

                    ! we fill first the matrix of A11 and A12
                    do var=0, 3
                        do eq=0, 3
                            x = eq * MM+j1
                            y = var * MM + j2

                            A11(x,y)=A11(x,y)+4d0*weight(j)*pi*A11bis(eq+1,var+1)
                            A12(x,y)=A12(x,y)+4d0*weight(j)*pi*A12bis(eq+1,var+1)
                        enddo

                        do eq=0, 2
                            x = eq * MM+j1
                            y = var * MM + j2

                            B11(x,y)=B11(x,y)+4d0*weight(j)*pi*B11bis(eq+1,var+1)
                            B12(x,y)=B12(x,y)+4d0*weight(j)*pi*B12bis(eq+1,var+1)
                        enddo
                    enddo
                    do var=0, 2
                        do eq=0, 3
                            x = eq * MM+j1
                            y = var * MM + j2

                            A21(x,y)=A21(x,y)+4d0*weight(j)*pi*A21bis(eq+1,var+1)
                            A22(x,y)=A22(x,y)+4d0*weight(j)*pi*A22bis(eq+1,var+1)
                        enddo

                        do eq=0, 2
                            x = eq * MM+j1
                            y = var * MM + j2

                            B21(x,y)=B21(x,y)+4d0*weight(j)*pi*B21bis(eq+1,var+1)
                            B22(x,y)=B22(x,y)+4d0*weight(j)*pi*B22bis(eq+1,var+1)
                        enddo
                    enddo

My issue is when I want to change my system of equations, I need to write one by one the different argument in each matrix. I would like to keep the matrix with the same number of arguments even if there is some dummy arguments. I know the argument sequence option but how can I precise inside the output of the computed matrix.
A little example here :
A=sy.Matrix.zeros(2,2)
A[0,0]=2*mu
A[0,1]=3*mu
A[1,0]=2*phi
A[1,1]=2*zeta
test=codegen(('eq1',A),'f95','test_routine_matrix2',to_files=True, argument_sequence=(zeta,mu,phi))

And I obtained the obvious error :
sympy.utilities.codegen.CodeGenArgumentListError: ("Argument list didn't specify: out_8094437834768287679 ", [OutputArgument(out_8094437834768287679, out_8094437834768287679, Matrix([
[ 2*\mu,   3*\mu],
[2*\phi, 2*\zeta]]))])


